# How to automate database backup using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am currently taking database backup manually using phpmyadmin export as a sql dump,the resulted file name will be spbkYYMMDD(Y;year m:month D:day).Is there any way to automate db backup so that i get sql dump for  regular intervals and the file name should automatically generated correspondingly .can you explain me the logic.

Comment: do u need it as a web interface to do ?

Comment: What do you mean by needing a web interface? What will you be having in the interface?

Comment: we can give the time backup interval text box to capture the time interval

Comment: @Vinay: check the answer. Have Updated it

Comment: You can simply use http://mysqlbackupftp.com/. Connect MySQLBackupFTP tool to your phpMyAdmin and create a schedule to backup your databases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run crontab in unix shell and create the rule to launch process for creating database backup

```
 0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/mysqldump -uLOGIN -PPORT -hHOST -pPASS DBNAME | gzip -c > `date “+\%Y-\%m-\%d”`.gz
```

Also check [this](http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f30/automated-remote-backup-using-ftp-commands-cron-job-12316/)

**EDIT**

The web interface you only have to write, dont think you can find a readymade code for that. But You need to use cron job, to automate a function to run at regular intervals in a unix machine. You can find more info on how to write a cron-job [here](http://www.webhostingresourcekit.com/190.html). So you now, just need to write a web interface, which gets data from user and changes the rule according to the input(Which I think you can do it yourselves)

Comment: mysqldump doesn't work from the outside if your DB server is only available on localhost or some [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) address.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11031535/219640 if you REALLY need to do this with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Remove those wierd quotes if date complains about the format: `“` : `date “+\%Y-\%m-\%d”` => `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`

Comment: Your "also check this" link is invalid or no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

The Code Will be Like This :

```
    @echo off
    for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DOW=%%i
    for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
    for /f %%i in ('echo %date_day:/=-%') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
    for /f %%i in ('time /t') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
    for /f %%i in ('echo %date_time::=-%') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
    "j:\xamppp\bin\mysqldump" -u root -p  --all-databases>j:\backupmysql\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_database.sql
```

**and save it as .bat and u can run it from task scheduler**

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a quick script for this exact use-case, since I had no access to the console for `mysqldump` and therefore needed it myself:

**Downloads:** [Github: phpmyadmin_sql_backup.py](https://github.com/qubitstream/phpmyadmin_sql_backup)

**Usage in your case:**

```
./phpmyadmin_sql_backup.py "https://www.example.com/phpmyadmin_login_page" USERNAME PASSWORD --basename "" --prepend-date --prefix-format "spbk%y%m%d" --overwrite-existing -o OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

Hopefully it proves to be useful for others.

Comment: python script is not working, error line 66: invalid syntax

Comment: Jerry1: You need to use Python 3 for this to work (as stated on the github page)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to automate MySQL DB backup is to use some backup software in conjunction with *phpmyadmin* utility. The second way, often having an advantage of no extra payment and a disadvantage of uncontrolled security, is implementing some script with *cron*.

Personally, I prefer Handy Backup in addition to my *phpMyAdmin*. See [the link to an article](http://www.handybackup.net/backup_terms/phpmyadmin.shtml) as an example. It is not hottest backup solution, but relatively cheap and very stable.

Answer (score 0):

Create .bat file in a folder when you have admin rights.
down here is a simple .bat file

```
cd "C:\XAMPP\mysql\bin"
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot ca > "D:\cash\bkcash\ca\db_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.sql"
```