# How can I automate the exportation of a mySQL database using phpMyAdmin

Tags: automation, phpmyadmin, export

Is it possible to automate the exportation of a single db using phpMyAdmin?

When I try creating the .sql file from an external script, like php, the resulting .sql file looks clean, but when imported causes problems in the application.

When I use phpMyAdmin to create a similar .sql file by using Export, the resulting .sql file Imports without causing any issues to my application.

The application is moodle 2.2, the MySQL version is 5.5, the phpMyAdmin version is 3.4.10.

Comment: I not checked it in phpMyAdmin, but maybe better solution will be make cron job.

Comment: I am using cron to call my external script that is problematic, which is why I would like to create the script directly from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You can connect MySQLBackupFTP (http://mysqlbackupftp.com/) to your phpMyAdmin and set a schedule to backup your databases automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to make a script that executes database export with [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) and after that a cronjob to execute that script.

Comment: since I am using a windows 2003 server, there is not a cron script avail. to automate.  I found the windows version of cron, AT, where I was able to use mysqldump, as you stated from the command line.

Comment: Cronjobs in Windows are called Scheduled Taks.

Comment: This works great until you're with a hosting company where the IP of the DB server is localhost or some [RFC 1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html) address and your only other access is FTP. Then your only access to our database is phpMyAdmin or via a homegrown PHP script, because you can't access the DB from the Internet.

Comment: Usually in those cases the hosting company will make some sort of cron scheduling tool available to you through your panel interface (cPanel, Plesk, ...).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't connect directly to the database with mysqldump, you can use this shell script (requires curl):

```
#!/bin/sh
ADMIN_URL='https://phpmyadmin.example.com'
USERNAME='my_username'
PASSWORD='my_password'
COOKIEJAR='/tmp/my_cookiejar'
token=`curl -s -o - -d "pma_username=$USERNAME" -d "pma_password=$PASSWORD" -c "$COOKIEJAR" "$ADMIN_URL/" | grep -o -m 1 "token=.*'" | sed "s/'//"`
curl -o - -b "$COOKIEJAR" -d what=sql -d export_type=server -d sql_structure_or_data=structure_and_data -d "$token" "$ADMIN_URL/export.php"
rm "$COOKIEJAR"
```

Then put it in your crontab:

```
22      3   *   *   *   someuser    /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/backup/db.sql
```

to get a backup at 3:22 every night.

Only tested with phpMyAdmin 3.4.10.1 and might not work in other (major) versions.

Comment: Looks like V4 has tokens in the form so I dont think this will work... Not tested though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script:
https://github.com/qubitstream/phpmyadmin_sql_backup

> phpmyadmin_sql_backup.py
>
> A Python 3 script to automate the download of SQL backups via a
>   phpMyAdmin web interface.
>
> This is useful when your web hosting provider does not grant you
>   access the the console (for mysqldump) but you want to automate the
>   backup of your database (without having to manually use the browser).
>
> It has been tested with Python 3.4+ on Linux and Windows and
>   phpMyAdmin 4.3.6, 4.5.4.1 and 4.7.0-dev
>
> Note: The web interface of phpMyAdmin may change in the future and
>   break this script. Please file a bug report (including your version of
>   phpMyAdmin) if you encounter this issue.

Example:

```
phpmyadmin_sql_backup.py "http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/" your_user your_password
```

other options available.