# Application for backup a MYSQL

Tags: mysql, windows, backup

I'm trying to backup MYSQL automatically on specified time every day, i searched for a free tool but i didn't find any thing !
Is there any free tool or application for backup a MYSQL database from my domain?

Comment: Do you have server access? What are your possibilities?

Comment: I have a domain just, and i bought it from a company.

Comment: have the ability to schedule cron jobs? if so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645818/how-to-automate-database-backup-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm asking for Windows application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**: If you are searching free tool for auto backup mysql then you should check this [Auto MY SQL Backup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/)

Features:

1. Email notification of backups
2. Backup Compression and Encryption
3. Configurable backup rotation
4. Incremental database backups

**Solution 2:**
Another Solution will be Cron Jobs

```
5 0 * * * /path/to/mysqldump ... > /path/to/backup/mydata_$( date +"%Y_%m_%d" ).sql
```

Read [man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date)

[How to (Cron)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

[Introduction to cron,covers the basics of what cron does,
and how to use it.](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

**Solution 3:**
For windows machines go for this link [windows auto backup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlbackupmanager/)

**solution 4:** In windows i would prefer Task Scheduler, it looks some thing like this

`schtasks /create /sc daily /st 08:20 /ru SYSTEM /tn MySQL_backup /tr "\"C:\My Project\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\dump.exe\" -B <DataBase_NAME> -u <USER_NAME> -p<PASSWORD> -r C:\MySQL_backup\<DataBase_NAME>_%date:~0,2%.sql`

I would prefer Cron Jobs. Hope this helps you.